# Cloth at a certain point of animation stuck in one place

Tags: cloth-simulation

I've been trying to dig up the history if anyone had a similar issue before, but nothing... so here's my problem:

I'm using cloth simulation in an animation, i.e., a rigged moving character model (pants, shirt); the simulation is OK for a while, however at a certain point it stops "simulating" and as my character moves ahead the cloths just remain in one place.

Anyone, any ideas what the issue can be, and a possible solution?

Cheers

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the simulation takes only 250 frames, adjust the "Simulation End":

[image]

Comment: Markus, thank you so much –– I knew it must be something trivial... Issue solved! Cheers!

Comment: if it fixes your poblem, mark the answer as correct  @MrFledermaus